# How to block application using messaging feature like sms in android

Tags: android

Hi I want to write an application that can prevent other application from using the sms feature of android mobile. That means other than sms feature of android mobile, no application  installed on phone can send sms message. How can this be implemented.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fortunately, this is not possible, except perhaps by custom firmware. Any app that holds the `SEND_SMS` permission is perfectly welcome to use `SmsManager` to send an SMS.

Comment: Fortunately?? Excuse me, but you have a very narrow attitude. There are legitimate cases where preventing the sending of SMS messages is more than justified - like a parent giving a teen girl a phone and limiting the number of messages she can send per day. You think too much like a damn programmer and not in the real world.